# Using CSS to change the brightness of one of the background images in a multiple image background?

Tags: html, css, filter

I tried the following code and it is not helping.

```
.information{    
    background-image:url(../images/needle_img.png),url(../images/broken_noise.png);
    background-size: auto 60%, auto auto;
    background-position:left bottom,top left;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(0.8),brightness(1);
    -moz-filter: brightness(0.7),brightness(1);
    -o-filter: brightness(0.8),brightness(1);
    -ms-filter: brightness(0.8),brightness(1);
    filter: brightness(0.8),brightness(1);
    background-repeat: no-repeat,repeat;

}
```

Comment: Why are you doing brightness(1) right after the other settings?

Comment: I don't want to change the brightness of broken_noise.png image.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even see that second image! My bad

Comment: I think the filter will be effective on element but not particularly on background property..

Comment: So i think if you really need this effect add one element on top or below with help of position property and apply filter to it.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't brighten the image before hand? Either manually or on the server?

Comment: @Sarcoma I thought of this solution before. I just wanted to know if there is any other solution.

Comment: @Manjunath Can you please give an example or some reference.

Comment: @bhavi I made a codepen https://codepen.io/mjn/pen/oMeyrx you can check and play with it to your needs :)

Comment: @Manjunath Thank you. I will let you know once I try it